# Finding velocity as a piecewise function of time given constant power

Tags: calculus, classical-mechanics

Initial problem: (see the very bottom for my actual question)
**Problem $13$*** ($5$ marks) A $4$ wheel drive car of mass $m$ accelerates from rest. The friction coefficient is $\mu$. The engine delivers a constant power to the wheels $P$. Find the relationship between the speed of the car and time. Write your answer as a function of time.

My attempt:
Firstly in this problem there are no drag forces resisting motion, the only horizontal force on the car is the total force of friction across all four tires from the road. The work done by the engine can all be assumed to go towards increasing the kinetic energy $KE$, the power $P$ is the rate of change of $KE$, as this is constant we can say at a time $t$, $KE=Pt\Rightarrow\frac12mv(t)^2=Pt\Rightarrow v(t)=\sqrt{\frac{2Pt}{m}}$. However this doesn't involve $\mu$, sketch $v(t):$
[velocity-time-graph-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4xg4.png)

Acceleration is the gradient in a velocity time graph and here the acceleration is infinite at time $t=0$ which implies infinite force. Differentiate $v(t)$ w.r.t. $t$:
$$a(t)=\frac{d}{dt}\sqrt{\frac{2Pt}{m}}=\sqrt{\frac{2P}{m}}\frac{d}{dt}\sqrt{t}=\sqrt{\frac{2P}{m}}\frac{1}{2\sqrt{t}}=\sqrt{\frac{P}{2mt}},$$
and clearly $a\rightarrow\infty$ as $t\rightarrow0$:
[acceleration-time-graph-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTp71.png)

We can resolve this as follows. The forward accelerating force on the car is provided by the frictional force of the ground on the tires, so it's maximum is $F_{max}=\mu R$ where $R$ is the whole of normal reaction of the ground on the car, the whole because it's $4$ wheel drive so each wheel contributes some of $F_{max}$ but $F_{max}$ is the total forward force.
[car-road-model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V99T1.png)
$R=mg$ due to vertical equilibrium, so $ma_{max}=\mu mg\Rightarrow a_{max}=\mu g,$ sketching this:
[acceleration-time-graph-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PcYF2.png)

So for $t$ less than some $t_1, a=\mu g$, for these values of $t,\:\sqrt{\frac{P}{2mt}}$ is greater than $\mu g\:$ so here $\mu g$ takes over and becomes the actual acceleration as it is the maximum that the acceleration can be, we can interpret this as: the force which the engine can provide from the torque of the axle is greater than the frictional force which the wheels can apply to the road) meaning only $\mu mg$ (max friction) of that force is applied on the road (and therefore on the tires by the road) this also means that the wheels are experiencing "dynamic friction". This forward frictional force gets transferred to the axle via normal contact force and accelerates the car body forward, as it also does in the static friction case but the rest of the force goes to additionally spinning the wheels in excess of what they would need to be spinning to provide the current acceleration given the grip that they have and causing them to "slip extra". But after $t_1$ seconds $a=\sqrt{\frac{P}{2mt}}<\mu g$, so **the previously derived acceleration function takes over purely because it's no longer being limited by the force which the ground can provide rather by the force which the engine can provide to the wheels** due to the increasing nature of the work required to increase $KE$ as velocity increases. When the $\sqrt{\frac{P}{2mt}}$ function takes over this is when the tires immediately start "gripping" in that wheels aren't over-slipping what they need to do, the nature of the forward force on the tires becomes "static friction" - the fact that it's now gripping doesn't mean that you get an increase in acceleration at this point rather the opposite, the rate of increase of velocity depends on the force that the wheels are being driven into the ground with. We can find $t_1$ by equating: $\mu g=\sqrt{\frac{P}{2mt_1}}\Rightarrow t_1=\frac{P}{2m\mu^2 g^2}$. Resketch the velocity graph:
[velocity-time-graph-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTk6v.png)

Similarly for $t<t_1$ the velocity function will have maximum acceleration, we can find this velocity by integrating $\mu g$ w.r.t. $t$ giving $\mu gt$ with no added constant since it starts from rest. We can verify the value of $t_1$ here by equating: $\mu gt_1=\sqrt{\frac{2Pt_1}{m}}\Rightarrow \mu^2g^2t_1^2=\frac{2Pt_1}{m}\Rightarrow t_1=\frac{2P}{m\mu^2g^2}$.

My question is why is this value of $t_1$ $4$ times greater than it was from using the acceleration? Surely the velocity function should go from having maximum gradient to decreasing gradient at the same time as the acceleration itself decreases from its maximum value. So if I were to write $v(t)$ as a piecewise function would I write:
$$v(t)=\begin{cases}\mu gt & \text{if }\: 0<t<\frac{P}{2m\mu^2g^2}\\ \sqrt{\frac{2pt}{m}} & \text{if }\: t\geq\frac{P}{2m\mu^2g^2}\end{cases}$$
or
$$v(t)=\begin{cases}\mu gt & \text{if }\: 0<t<\frac{2P}{m\mu^2g^2}\\ \sqrt{\frac{2pt}{m}} & \text{if }\: t\geq\frac{2P}{m\mu^2g^2}\end{cases}$$
Apologies for being long winded in that friction section but I have really tried to emphasise why I believe that the acceleration should be a piecewise function, since certain limitations of the force on the tires are changing.

Comment: Why does your solution possess two stages ? And it doesn't seem physical, since the truck velocity increases (linearly) because of the friction during the first stage (even though friction should decreases the velocity, of course), without any influence of the motor power $P$, while the friction doesn't affect the motion in the second phase.

Comment: @Abezhiko - Firstly there are no drag forces resisting motion at all in this problem, the frictional force I refer to is the forward force of the road surface on the tires. The power of the engine provides a torque on the axle which drives the wheels into the ground applying a backwards frictional force on the ground, the ground applies an equal and opposite forward frictional force on the tires, there are two stages of this force's behaviour: one where the friction is maximum (this resolves the infinite force problem mentioned) and during this time the wheels may even be spinning on the

Comment: ground and not gripping fully but still feeling the maximum (dynamic friction) force of $\mu R$, and then as increasing work needs to be done by the engine to increase velocity, the acceleration required drops below the maximum acceleration permitted by the ground and the wheels start to grip and experience static friction only, still a forward force but less than $\mu R$, so here is when the initially derived velocity equation takes over, simply because it is no longer being limited in terms of its acceleration.

Comment: I think I've figured it out, my initial equation $KE=Pt$ is only valid given that energy is conserved but energy is not conserved when the wheels are slipping on the ground

Comment: I think you overcomplicated the problem by considering those two stages. You should fix $t = 0$ when the truck in on the point of moving, so that you needn't consider the static friction anymore, even if the initial velocity is zero (or more exactly infinitesimal, but that is the same in the point of view of physical precision). Anyway, static and dynamic frictions are not identical and only one of them is given to you (the dynamical one), that is why there is no need to consider this first stage.

Comment: Moreover, I think you misapplied the action-reaction principle, since the friction force is not a reaction to the motor traction, even if it is compensated by the latter. In addition, the friction doesn't disappears after the truck starts to move, although you seem to consider to an effective traction.

Comment: ok, I understand what your saying, although I believe that the car would still accelerate under dynamic friction?

Comment: It accelerates if $\dot{v} = \frac{P}{mv} - \mu g > 0$. This condition is clearly satisfied at the beginning, but it may not be the case at high speed. Eventually the velocity will stabilize.

Answer (score 0):

Here we have four forces : the gravity $\vec{F}_g = -mg\,\hat{e}_y$, the normal force $\vec{F}_n = F_n\,\hat{e}_y$, the friction $\vec{F}_f = -F_f\,\hat{e}_x$ and the motor traction $\vec{F}_m = F_m\,\hat{e}_x$. Newton's second law implies
$$
m\vec{a} = \vec{F}_g + \vec{F}_n + \vec{F}_f + \vec{F}_m,
$$
hence $F_n = mg$ and $F_f = \mu F_n = \mu mg$. The engine force may be deduced from its power, with $F_m = \frac{P}{v}$. The horizontal equation of motion is thus :
$$
m\dot{v} = \frac{P}{v} - \mu mg
$$
It is nonlinear and cannot be solved as easily as you did, without stronger hypothesis.

If you want to make energy considerations, you should start from this basic principle : the difference in mechanical energy is due the work of non-conservative forces, with the friction and the motor traction being the non-conservative forces in the present case. Mathematically, it is translated by
$$
\Delta E_{mec} = E_{mec}(t_2) - E_{mec}(t_1) = W_f(t_1\rightarrow t_2) + W_m(t_1\rightarrow t_2),
$$
which becomes $\dot{E}_{mec} = P_f + P_m$ in the continuous limit. The friction power is given by $P_{\vec{F}_f} = \vec{F}_f \cdot \vec{v} = -F_fv = -\mu mgv$, while the engine power $P_m = P$ is constant. On the other hand, given that the potential energy stays the same, one has $\dot{E}_{mec} = \dot{E}_{kin} = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\left(\frac{1}{2}mv^2\right) = mv\dot{v}$. Again, we end up with the differential equation
$$
\dot{v} = \frac{P}{mv} - \mu g,
$$
which is not trivial.

Comment: about your solution, I think that the $F_m =\frac{P}{v}$ power, force, velocity equation which you mention only applies for constant velocity.

Comment: I appreciate your answer but it's way above my high school level, I still think that my problem is resolvable using high school level concepts

Comment: @Edrawrxd  $P = \vec{F} \cdot \vec{v}$ is also valid for non-constant velocity; it is the relation $W = \vec{F} \cdot \vec{x} = Pt$ which is actually true for constant velocity only.

Comment: @Edrawrxd  I see... In that case, your teacher didn't choose a suitable problem for your level, unless some unsaid symplifying hypothesis is assumed.